# Discrete Math onto function question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone tell me if:

$\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

$F(x) = 3x^2 + 1$

Is it onto?

I'm pretty sure it's not because $x^2$ itself isn't onto, but I need second opinions...

Why am I getting down-voted? I just want help..

Comment: What is the definition you have that involves "onto" ?

Comment: You say $F(\color{red}{x})=3\color{red}{n}^2+1$.  Which is it $x$ or $n$?  As far as I can tell with the way it is written your function is constant.  Fixing your typo to be $f(x)=3x^2+1$, ask yourself if there are any elements in the codomain that never get mapped to and have no preimage?  Is a real number squared ever negative?

Comment: You fixed your typo that I pointed out, so you are apparently listening.  Can you answer pjs36's question?  What does it mean for a function to be onto?  What does it mean for a function to not be onto?  Can you answer my question?  Is a real number squared ever negative?  Can you use these two answers to our questions to formulate a definitive answer to your question yourself?

Comment: Haha, yeah sorry about that. No, a real number squared is positive. So then it is onto? Considering x can be positive or negative and you get will get the same F(x)?

Comment: I assume you know what "onto" means. Is there a real number x such that f(x)=0?

Comment: @user254665 I think this is an unwarranted assumption, judging by the comment above yours: it seems "onto" and "one-to-one" are being conflated and... negated? I don't really know.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, a function f from a set X to a set Y is surjective (or onto), or a surjection, if every element y in Y has a corresponding element x in X such that f(x) = y. (It is not required that x is unique; the function f may map one or more elements of X to the same element of Y.)  For your problem our set X is $\Bbb R$ and our set Y is $\Bbb R$. But, if we pick 0, in our set Y, can we find an x in X such that f(x) = y ?

This is not onto, because the function does not "hit" all of $\Bbb R$. Can you see that it is only mapping to the positive real numbers? Also, people will tend to down vote if they feel that you didn't put a lot of effort into your question/ editing it to make it presentable.

Comment: Thank you! I'm very slowly understanding this. I really should have noticed that mistake though.. It's super understandable.

Comment: No problem, here is an example of an "onto", also know as "surjective" function from Wikipedia: The function f : R → R defined by f(x) = 2x + 1 is surjective (and even bijective), because for every real number y we have an x such that f(x) = y: an appropriate x is (y − 1)/2.

Comment: In mathematics, a function f from a set X to a set Y is surjective (or onto), or a surjection, if every element y in Y has a corresponding element x in X such that f(x) = y. (It is not required that x is unique; the function f may map one or more elements of X to the same element of Y.)  For your problem our set X is $\Bbb R$ and our set Y is $\Bbb R$. But, if we pick 0, in our set Y, can we find an x in X such that f(x) = y ?